# Add div outer of an image tag with ruby gsub or jquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have an HTML string containing multiple `<image>` tags.  I'd like to search for each tag and  wrap them with a `div` tag.

For example:

```
mplampla<img src="somethin.jpg" />mplampal
```

Should be:

```
mplampla<div class=""><img src="something" /></div>mplamla
```

How can I do this using Regex within Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I properly understand what you need:

```
foo = 'mplampla<img src="somethin.jpg" />mplampal'
re = re = /(?<img><img .*? \/>)/
foo.gsub re, '<div>\k<img></div>'
# => "mplampla<div><img src=\"somethin.jpg\" /></div>mplampal"
```

Here we're using named capturing groups using the \k named backreference syntax: `(?<img>...)` creates named group and `\k<img>` uses backreference.

**UPDATED**

We also have to use non-greedy quantificator - thanks @mu! - for working with nested tags

Comment: Oops, you're perfectly right, thanks a lot!! Now trying to use non-greedy matching :)

Answer (score 4):

This is jquery solution

```php
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.image').wrap('<div class="">');
});
</script>
<img class="image" src="img.jpg" />
<img class="image" src="img.jpg" />
<img class="image" src="img.jpg" />
<img class="image" src="img.jpg" />
```